# want my image or pdf files to be opened through the default viewer of iPhone from my ios app

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uidocumentinteraction

I have my app with diff format files like .jpg, .png, .pdf, .mkv... and these are coming from aws as url...i want to open each url with native viewer.

Please help.

Comment: you can open this file using UIWebview. What is your exact requirment?

Comment: I want to build my own native viewer.

Comment: ok then you use uiwebview

Comment: i think you just need a third part tool, which works like  a native browser. here is the [link](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=webview)

Answer (score 0):

You can show your image, pdf in an UIWebview like this

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSURL *yourFileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Your image or pdf path"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:yourFileURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: this i dont need actually.

Comment: ios have not any default pdf viewer you have to download any viewer